# Concatenando coluna quando deve somente ler uma entrada

Tags: r

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
library(data.table)

setwd("/home/andre/monografia/") ; getwd()

obj = read.csv(file = "Grup1C0.csv");

tes = obj[4,4]

View(tes)
```

A estrada que está na posição `[4,4]` do objeto `obj` é uma *string* de 45 caracteres, mas quando verifico qual foi o valor atribuído ao objeto `tes` tenho como resultado todas as entradas da coluna 4 em um só vetor.

**Como faço para ter somente a *string* de meu interesse no `tes`?**

Comment: André, tente criar um exemplo reproduzível, pois não é possível replicar o seu exemplo. Se `obj` for um `data.frame` ele irá retornar o valor da linha 4 coluna 4. Se `obj` for um `data.table` ele irá retornar o valor "4". Em nenhum dos casos o resultado seria todos os valores da coluna 4.

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi o problema alterando a função `read.csv`. Segue a linha para exemplo:

`Grup1C0 <- read.csv("~/monografia/Grup1C0.csv", row.names=1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

O argumento realmente é importante, é o `StringAsFactors`.

Comment: André, ainda bem que resolveu o problema. Entretanto não parece estar claro como isso ocorreu, já que esse atributo `StringAsFactors` não parece estar relacionado com o seu problema. Poderia elaborar melhor o que mudou, por favor?